# How to join two objects in Rally

Tags: rally

I would like to join the user object and project permission object to see how many users have been assigned to a project, for audit purpose. I don't see a common field with common values (email address or first name/last name) between these objects. I used Excel plugin to retrieve two separate data sheet and unable to map them. Any thoughts on this on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably seeing something similar to the following when you query on ProjectPermissions:

[image: UserProjectPermissions1]

In this situation, the default User object selected from the "Columns" picker in the query dialog, gives you the User's DisplayName, which doesn't unambiguously map to a Rally UserID.

Note, however, that you can add dot-notation sub-fields of Objects manually by typing them into the Columns field. In the following example, I've included `User.Username` and `User.LastLoginDate` as additional fields I want to show on the Permissions report:

[image: UserProjectPermissions2]

Of course, you could also just include User.Username, and run a second query on the User object with all fields selected, and do a join in Excel.

One note of caution - if you have many users (say 1,000), and a lot of projects, (say 1,000, which is not uncommon in large Rally subscriptions), querying directly against the ProjectPermissions endpoint can rapidly result in total results that number on the order of 10^6. This will probably time out in an Excel query.

The [Rally User Management: User Permissions Summary](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management/blob/master/user_permissions_summary.rb) script works around this by querying Permissions in a loop on a user-by-user basis. It's slow, but it returns results without timeouts. Certainly not as convenient as Excel either - you need to install Ruby 1.9.2+ and the [rally_api](http://rubygems.org/gems/rally_api) gem to get it working.